# Unable to Sign In to Visual Studio 2015

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, msdn

I'm having trouble with "sign in" function in VS 2015. After entering my username\password data i'm getting

> A network connection attempt has timed out. This could be a problem
>   either with our service or your local network connection.

But I can connect to live.com and msdn.com easily. What's the problem could be?

Comment: Really would like to see an answer to this, as I'm having trouble with it as well.  The Featured Videos on the Start Page will also not display, stating "We are unable to download content due to network issues."

Comment: I am also having this problem, I am certain my password is correct. Time spent battling Visual Stupid: 99%. Time spent doing actual work: 1%. Hurray for professional, expensive tooling.

Comment: It didn't work for me in the office because of the office proxy server. When I connected with my Home network without any Proxy server it worked. Only additional thing it asked was for additional approval either from APP or Mobile or email.

Answer (score 8):

The resolution for me was to changed my Visual Studio proxy settings:

C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config

from:

`<system.net>
    <settings>
        <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
    </settings>
</system.net>`

to:

`<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
        <proxy usesystemdefault="True" />
    </defaultProxy>
    <settings>
        <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
    </settings>
</system.net>`

Comment: This resolved a number of issues I was experiencing with Visual Studio (no news on start page, NuGet not working). Thank you!

Comment: although I had done similar changes in the machine.config file which resolved my problem.

Answer (score 2):

My resolution was exactly the opposite to that which worked for @devries48:

Open `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe.config`

Locate `system.net` node and change this from:

```
<system.net>
    <defaultProxy useDefaultCredentials="true" enabled="true">
        <proxy usesystemdefault="True" />
    </defaultProxy>
    <settings>
        <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
    </settings>
</system.net>
```

to:

```
<system.net>
    <settings>
        <ipv6 enabled="true"/>
    </settings>
</system.net>
```

It will depend on your (corporate) proxy settings for which approach will work best for you. If you have other instances of Visual Studio you can compare the settings in the configuration for these instances too:

- **VS 2017** - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE`
- **VS 2013** - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE`
- **VS 2010** - `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Common7\IDE`